# Clarification on rollback regarding black lightsabers?

Tags: discussion, editing, citations

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55396/23243

Not complaining, just curious as to whether I erred in adding Wookiepedia citations to a too-brief answer given my edit got rolled back before the question was closed as a duplicate. I'd ask Keen directly, but Stack Exchange seems opposed to direct contact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll just restate my comment:

> @SeanDuggan That edit was way too drastic.  You completely overhauled the answer, and that's not [what edits are for](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

The answer as originally posted was incorrect (I think).  You completely rewrote it so that it indicated how incorrect it was.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Sorry for the double-post. I made the comment, then decided that the odds were good that you would get no notification that I was asking you, since the system did not give any indication that I had tagged you.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Yeah, I faced the same issue when I rolled it back. :3

Answer (score 5):

I'll chime in here, since [I brought up the edits in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17152433#17152433)

The original answer was posted. Personally, I think it's wrong, but that's neither here nor there.

Your additions, while full of good intentions, actually went too far trying to back up the answer with citations.

Particularly

> It also was not entirely black, and glowed with a dark purple hue:
>
> The blade took on a deep violet hue and consisted of an obsidian-colored core with blood-red flecks flashing up and down the blade's length.

Which actually contradicts their offering of the soulsaber as a black lightsaber.

By adding as much as you did, you effectively took a poor answer and turned it into an answer that contradicts itself. That's far too drastic of an edit for my taste, and I would have rejected it, had it come across the review queue.

Comment: Improving an answer beyond recognition is still vandalism.